# Flashbuilder "to the power of N"

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flashbuilder4

How can I have the ^-N in the statement below mean "to the power of -N" in Flashbuilder?
Thanks

```
var M:Number =  1 - (1 + J)^-N;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var M:Number = 1 - Math.pow(1 + J, -N);
```

Answer (score 1):

Colin is correct, use the Math.pow(val1:Number, val2:Number):Number method.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Math.html#pow()